# How can i transfer data between ng controllers ( with localhost link api )

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a buttonclick on my tr,  After i press on my tr, i want it to transfer the data that was inside of that tr to the next ng-controller.

I've been searching much for solution but it looks like i need to make a angular.module and connect the controllers together? or does it work with a localhostlink? You dont need to solve it, im totaly stuck, just some advice would be nice. Thank you in advance.

```
<div ng-controller="customersController">

    <table>
        <tr ng-click=getid(order) ng-repeat="x in Id">
            <td>{{ x.firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.lastname}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>

<div ng-controller="showinfo">

    <p>id:{{ x.firstname}}</p>
    <p>name:{{ x.lastname}}</p>


</div>
```

this is my script

```
     function customersController($scope, $http) {    


      $scope.getid= function (order) {



        };

        $http.get("localhostlink")
            .success(function (response) {
                $scope.Id = response;});
     }
```

Comment: Why are you using two different controllers ? You can put several div inside a same general controller, and everything will be binded and automatically updated.

Comment: later on i will only show 1 div at the time, so when u press on buttonclick, div 1 will be hidden, and div 2 pop up

Comment: ok it is not a problem : the top div contains the unique controller, and inside this div, you have 2 div with ng-show... it is really important to avoid using isolated controllers like you do.

Comment: oh ok ty, but how can i still solve it? if i change it now to same ng controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same controller by doing :

```
<div ng-controller="customersController"> 
   <div>

        <table>
            <tr ng-click=getid(x) ng-repeat="x in Id">
                <td>{{ x.firstname }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.lastname}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>

    <div>

        <p>id:{{ currentSelection.firstname}}</p>
        <p>name:{{ currentSelection.lastname}}</p>


    </div>
</div>
```

With the script :

```
function customersController($scope, $http) {    

   $scope.currentSelection = {};

   $scope.getid= function (order) {

      $scope.currentSelection.firstname = order.firstname;
      $scope.currentSelection.lastname = ordername;  

   };

    $http.get("localhostlink").success(function (response) {
            $scope.Id = response;});
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, its working. i just wonder why u changed ng-cklick to getid(x) from getid(order), and why u used order after = in the script

Comment: In the JS code "order" is a local variable that you can name like you want... just matter of copy/paste :)

Comment: ok, but what about the getid(x) instead of my getid(order) , does it have something to do x.name table?

Comment: It seams like you "order" variable is never defined anywhere in you scope (controller). "x" is defined in the ng-repeat scope only.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the controllers to communicate with each other, use Services and $rootScope (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) provided by AngularJS then inject it to all controllers that need to communicate.

Here is one great example : http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/XqDxG/

```js
myModule.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {
    var sharedService = {};
    
    sharedService.message = '';

    sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(msg) {
        this.message = msg;
        this.broadcastItem();
    };

    sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    };

    return sharedService;
});
```

Credit: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-communicating-between-controllers/